# ionic variable treated as plaintext?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm writing an ionic application and I have a problem. I'm note sure where the problem is here but I have this code

```
<div ng-if="ads.length > 0" class="card advertisement itemdetail">
    <ks-swiper-container
        autoplay="5000"
        speed="300"
        loop="true"
        show-nav-buttons="false"
        space-between="5"
        pagination-clickable="false"
        pagination-is-active="false"
    >
        <ks-swiper-slide class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="ad in ads">
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <a target="_blank" ng-href="{{ad.web}}" onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'location=no'); return false;">
                    <img src="{{ad.ad}}"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </ks-swiper-slide>
    </ks-swiper-container>
</div>
```

Now the problem is that when the `ads` variable is empty (if it's not, everything works as expected), I'm getting this error in my browser console:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8100/{{ad.ad}}`

So my question is, why is it trying to load `http://localhost:8100/{{ad.ad}}`? Why is the `{{ad.ad}}` variable treated as plaintext? Shouldn't this all be skipped because the `ads.length` is 0?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this seems to have solved my issue: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc